# SASS project setup: mixins that depend on other mixins

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

I organizing my sass (scss) files in the way outlined [here](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)...

```
stylesheets/
|
|-- modules/              # Common modules
|   |-- _all.scss         # Include to get all modules
|   |-- _utility.scss     # Module name
|   |-- _colors.scss      # Etc...
|   ...
|
|-- partials/             # Partials
|   |-- _base.sass        # imports for all mixins + global project variables
|   |-- _buttons.scss     # buttons
|   |-- _figures.scss     # figures
|   |-- _grids.scss       # grids
|   |-- _typography.scss  # typography
|   |-- _reset.scss       # reset
|   ...
|
|-- vendor/               # CSS or Sass from other projects
|   |-- _colorpicker.scss
|   |-- _jquery.ui.core.scss
|   ...
|
`-- main.scss            # primary Sass file
```

I understand the purpose of differentiating **partials** and **modules**: partials output css whereas modules define mixins, variables, etc that are more easily reused.

**My question:**
What if I want to write a module that uses mixins from *another* module? For example, I have a module that defines a mixin for media queries. I have another module that defines a mixin for scaling typo responsively (adjusting line-height, font-size, etc). I want the latter to use my responsive mixin, but I don't want to copy/paste the first module into the second. Should I just @import the first into the second? What's the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

Whichever file is the dependancey you would import it first.

I like to keep my structure fairly flat and just import everything into one main.scss file.

```
@import "variables";
@import "base-classes";
@import "mixins";

@import "fonts";
@import "typography";

@import "elements";

@import "layouts/spree_application";

@import "orders";

@import "products/show";

@import "shared/breadcrumbs";
@import "shared/feed";
@import "shared/footer";
@import "shared/header";
@import "shared/subscribe";
@import "shared/taxonomies";

// Checkout pages
@import "checkout/edit";
@import "checkout/summary";

@import "checkout/delivery";
@import "checkout/payment";
@import "checkout/confirm";

// Pages
@import "lookbooks";

@import "news/index";
@import "news/show";

@import "stockists";
@import "surfclub";
@import "about";
@import "returnsexchanges";
```

Comment: My understanding is that the modules are intended to be reusable. For this reason, I'm looking for a way to handle the dependency so that  things don't break later if I want to use one module but not the other. Does that make sense? Your answer doesn't solve my problem. It is what I'm doing now and it's perfectly fine within the scope of a single project. But I'm looking for a long-term solution that avoids coupling as much as possible.